# Installing multiple instances of postgres on suse

Tags: linux, postgresql

Is there a HOWTO out there somewhere that explains how to install multiple instances of Postgres on a SUSE server?  Im building a test environment and need to have about 2 or 3 instances of postgres running on the box, otherwise i have to build the same number of linux servers which will suck.

Comment: Did you search for it already or this is your first stop?

Comment: i have searched for it but all i can find so far are documents on how to prevent multiple copies from opening.  nothing outlining how to run multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

I found several links on Google showing how to do this, and all I had to type was [`postgre multiple instances`](https://www.google.ca/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=postgre%20multiple%20instances&oq=postgre%20multiple%20instances&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=igoogle.3...885l5779l0l6276l26l25l0l13l13l0l161l1329l2j10l12l0.).

Here's one that seems pretty good: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/install_multiple_postgresql_servers_redhat_linux/